# MYSQL Select By This Week

Tags: mysql

I would like to have user can see their uploaded images by this week.

Is this correct?

```
"SELECT * 
FROM images 
WHERE userid = '$userid' 
  AND uploadeddate >= DATEPART(week, uploadeddate) = DATEPART(week, GETDATE()) 
ORDER BY uploadeddate DESC";
```

I am getting error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Tagged as `mysql` with a `sql-server` date function? My guess is `mysql` because of `$userid`.

Comment: What database are you using? You tagged MySQL but the syntax looks like SQL Server?

Comment: Mind to share the error text with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    images
WHERE   userid = $userid
        AND uploadeddate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(day) DAY
        AND uploadeddate < CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(day) DAY + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Create an index on `(userid, uploadeddate)` for this to work fast.

Answer (score 0):

The below queries will return records for the *current* week. It's also best practice to specify a column list in your `SELECT`.

If you're using SQL Server:

```
SELECT ... WHERE DATEPART(week, uploadeddate) = DATEPART(week, GETDATE())
```

If you're using MySQL:

```
SELECT ... WHERE WEEK(uploadeddate) = WEEK(CURDATE())
```